# Razor's Umbraco.media throws error when no image is uploaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, umbraco

I'm making a bunch of content boxes to render to the master. They all contain a background picture, a heading and content, all are ment to be optional. so if none = empty divs. -> removed.

it all seemed allright i used the @Umbraco.Field for text and @Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.myMediaAlias).url for the bg picture. Using 'media picker' as datatype.

No problem leaving the heading and content fields blank.
But the problem started when there was no picture defined for the last box.
i got the:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   [No relevant source lines]

Since it is supposed to be optional to put in that picture, i would rather want a null back.
The media picker property is not mandatory. How can i get this to work?

@section contentMid2 {

```
<div class="c-box-wrapper">

     <div class="c-box" id="c-box-3" Style="background-image: url(@Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.box3Bg).Url )" >   
        <div class="transbox">

                        <div class="home-head-1"> @Umbraco.Field("mainHeading3") </div>
                        <div class="content-text1"><p>@Umbraco.Field("mainContent3")</p></div>

        </div>



</div>



}
```

Comment: You have to check `@Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.box3Bg)` if it's null before requesting for it's `Url`. Try to do this in a separate variable above the `<div>` and use that variable for `Style` attribute.

Comment: That was actually my first go at it, i've tried it again and tried googling a bit more and found " if() inside `<Div>` tag" as for less code. but i keep getting this error i get each time i try to use `@Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.box3Bg)`in queries: _The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.Media(params int[])' and 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.Media(params string[])'_

Answer (score 0):

Untested - but something like this should work.  They key being to use HasValue

```
if(@CurrentPage.HasValue("box3Bg"){
     <div class="c-box" id="c-box-3" Style="background-image: url(@Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.box3Bg).Url )" >
}
else{
     <div class="c-box" id="c-box-3">
}
```

OR

```
@{
     var inlineStyle = "";
     if(@CurrentPage.HasValue("box3Bg"){
         inlineStyle = background-image: url(@Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.box3Bg).Url )
     }
}
<div class="c-box-wrapper">
   <div class="c-box" id="c-box-3" Style="@inlineStyle" >   
     <div class="transbox">
        <div class="home-head-1"> @Umbraco.Field("mainHeading3") </div>
        <div class="content-text1"><p>@Umbraco.Field("mainContent3")</p></div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

After some debuging and some help from @marco. i realized how to fix it:

```
<div class="c-box" id="c-box-3" Style="background-image: url(@(Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.box3Bg.ToString())!=""?Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.box3Bg).Url:Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.box1Bg).Url))" >
```

It's a Shorthand, and still inside the style url: `@(theobj!=empty?nah:yah)` works like a charm.
But i had to convert `theobj` `.ToString()` before comparing or it or else it seems like `.Media` cant decide if it's int or string. even if the question was if it's nothing in there at all.